# How to rerandomize plots on a grid with math.random

Tags: java, random, methods, grid

I am assigning 3 chars (two 'T's and one 'S') to a 10 x 10 grid. I have that down but I want to know how I could re randomize the char's positions if they end up on the same spot. Basically I am creating a little game where I am a soldier (S) and am on a grid with two Targets (T). Eventually I will have to eliminate the targets but I fist I want to make sure each one ends up in it's own spot. [here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C91JO.png)

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class PaintBall_Thomas{
    public static void fillGrid(char[][] battleField){
      for ( int i = 0; i < battleField.length; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j < battleField[i].length; j++){
          battleField[i][j] = '-';
        }
      }
      battleField[((int)(Math.random()*10))][((int)(Math.random()*10))] = 'S';//assigns a random number between 1-10 and assigns it to either soldier/target
      battleField[((int)(Math.random()*10))][((int)(Math.random()*10))] = 'T';
      battleField[((int)(Math.random()*10))][((int)(Math.random()*10))] = 'T';
      for ( int i = 0; i < battleField.length; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j < battleField[i].length; j++){

          System.out.print(battleField[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }//end of fillGrid method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int columns = 10;
      int rows = 10;
      System.out.println("----------GRID----------");
      //end of main
      char[][] battleField = new char [rows][columns];
      fillGrid(battleField);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be a good use for recursion, so like

```
public void addChar(char type) {
    int row = (int)(Math.random() * battleField.length); // choose rand spot
    int col = (int)(Math.random() * battleField.length);

    if (battleField[row][col] == '-') { // if chosen space is free
        battleField[row][col] = type; // add it
    } else {
        addChar(type) // try again if space was occupied
    }
}
```

so this could have some problems... such as possibilities of getting a stack overflow if the board is already full... but if the method's only intended use is to add the two Ts and one S, it should be fine

so you could just add them like

```
addChar('T');
addChar('T');
addChar('S');
```

and none of the chosen spots will be duplicates

Comment: Thank you! Heading to work now but I will try it when I get back home.